# comparing length of node values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In `Cypher`, how can I compare the length of two values using `Length` and `substring`.. like this

```
length(n.VALUE)= length(SUBSTRING(INPUT_STRING, 0,length(n.VALUE)))
```

I always get this exception when using this syntax:

```
SubstringFunction expected to be of type Collection but it is of type String
```

Answer (score 2):

The `length` function as it stands is meant to be used with collections. There is currently no way to get a length of a string in cypher. I've started work on adding a bunch of new string functions like `soundex` and `charindex`, and I'll throw this one on the stack of things to do, but I probably won't get it finished for a couple more weeks (and it needs to go through acceptance and even then will only be available as M05+, probably).

Comment: Well, thanks for your hint, but can I use any workaround to this trick??

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in your query? make sure that one string length is less than another string length?

Comment: the simpler way to do it is `length(n.VALUE) <= length(INPUT_STRING)`, but that won't work until `length()` can work on strings. I've put some more thought into this--maybe strings need to be treated as collections of characters for many other functions. I'll run this by the neo guys to see what they think.

Comment: Thanks Wes, but my condition must be `length(n.VALUE) = length(SUBSTRING(INPUT_STRING))`.. and it's the problem.. I wish it would be handled so soon as possible as I really need this condition

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing with your condition. What are possible values of n.VALUE and INPUT_STRING, and possible outcomes of the condition: true/false?

Comment: The n.VALUE would contains or equals substring of the Input_STRING, so I have to compare these two values and when the outcome is TRUE I will continue my query..

Comment: ...So.... Did you ever get around to that function? I'm currently learning neo4j and love it (thanks). I'm kinda stuck here though and couldn't find much through some semi-extensive Googling

Comment: it's called size() in latest versions.